# Two Ubuntu One shortcuts in Places menu

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-one, shortcuts, places

[image: 2 shortcuts]

After updating Ubuntu One, I'm stuck with 2 shortcuts to Ubuntu One in my Places menu. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please can you [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+filebug), and assign it to me? This shouldn't happen.

You can remove the second bookmark by opening Nautilus, and removing the bookmark from the "Places" sidepane:
[image: removing the Ubuntu One bookmark]

Comment: lol just as I was done typing :P

Comment: I've had this problem for more than a month now, probably from the update of the 10th december. Is it still worth to file a bug?

Comment: Yes, please do!

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a folder,
2. Click "bookmarks" in your menu,
3. Click edit bookmarks,
4. Select the duplicated and click remove.